# How to use tmpfs and SSD for smart cache

Tags: linux, ssd, cache, lvm, tmpfs

I want to create fast logical disk under Linux for storing temporary files. This files I don't afraid to lost.

On my machine I have 128Gb of RAM and 512Gb of SSD disk. So I want use 50% of my RAM as tmpfs and 50% of SSD disk for this cache, because some times it's not enough 50% of my RAM for cache and when tmpfs disk is full I want to use 50% of my SSD for write files. But when it's enough space on tmpfs it must use only tmpfs.

How can I achieve this strategy for my cache? May be some LVM with priorities? How can I settings up this?

Answer (score 0):

1. first you should be clear if you want a cache or fast storage,
   storage cannot be at the same time used as a cache and as storage too.
2. you did not mention what should happen in the case if you delete a file from the ram storage part when it is full and there are files on ssd

   - should the files move automatically from ssd (even partial?)
   - or stay at current location
3. and what about the case of a file partially spilling over to ssd?

   - should it be whole on ssd
   - or partially on ramdisk

maybe have a read http://blog-vpodzime.rhcloud.com/?p=45

my suggestion is :
use ssd space as filesystem and leave memory free - it will be automatically used as file cache by OS

another possibility is using ZFS on ssd , then set ARC size to desired memory cache size

Comment: 1. I want fast storage as possible
2. Good question, I just want don’t worry about this. May be it must be not 'file granularly', but 'cluster granularly', so if we have some free space on RAM-disk next writes blocks must be written on RAM disk.
3. Answered in previous 

About OS cache: As far as I know OS cache have some guarantees that information not be lost, so OS some times flushs block to the slow disk. I don’t want this performance degradation

Comment: the performance degradation happens on writes and can be mitigated with disabling synchronous access , depends on the selected filesystem, have a look at settings like data=writeback ,commit=nrsec,nobarrier

Comment: have you tried tuning parameters like https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/22/better-linux-disk-caching-performance-vm-dirty_ratio/

Comment: also do not use discard option of ext4 on ssd, its slow and it is better to perform fstrim in regular intervals

Comment: i think the most realistic solution is to have two filesystems and let application level decide which to use

Comment: another option would be to make a FUSE layer but FUSE is slow

Comment: another option is monitor the tmpfs free space and when its too low then move files to ssd and place symlinks and move back when there is enough space, using inotify ,probably best written in python